# convert json data to object in component.ts

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular6-json-schema-form

I have json data and I want to convert it into object format for doing a create operation.

> **json**

```
[
{
    "user": {
        "id": 83,
        "username": "das",
        "first_name": "dsafha",
        "last_name": "dfksdfk",
        "email": "sasda@gmail.com",
        "is_active": true,
        "is_superuser": false
    },
    "role": "testBu"
},
{
    "user": {
        "id": 84,
        "username": "sadfds",
        "first_name": "dshhgds",
        "last_name": "fsdjsl",
        "email": "fdjgd@gmail.com",
        "is_active": true,
        "is_superuser": false
    },
    "role": "testeditrole"
},
{
    "user": {
        "id": 86,
        "username": "fs",
        "first_name": "efhks",
        "last_name": "sofdh",
        "email": "fdshk@gmail.com",
        "is_active": true,
        "is_superuser": false
    },
    "role": "testeditrole"
},
{
    "user": {
        "id": 87,
        "username": "xz",
        "first_name": "vj",
        "last_name": "vkfd",
        "email": "sdsl@gmail.com",
        "is_active": true,
        "is_superuser": false
    },
    "role": "testeditrole"
}
]
```

I tried doing it like this

> **componet.ts**

```
let user:any = {};
   user["username"] = this.user.user.email
   user["first_name"] = this.user.user.first_name
   user["last_name"]= this.user.user.last_name
   user["email"]= this.user.user.email

   this.userData["user"] = user
   this.userData["role"] = this.user.role
```

and while consoling after entering the data into the input fields,I'm not getting the role data. I do get the other data. The role data appears empty. I do think its because of how i wrote the code in componet.ts that's causing the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always create models:

```
export class User {
 id: string,
 username: string,
 first_name: string,
 last_name: string,
 email: string,
 is_active: boolean,
 is_superuser: boolean
}
    
export class UserDetails{
 user:User;
 role:string;
}
```

Then:

```
// Assume you have received the json in string form in
'resultlist' variable
let dataList = <Array<UserDetails>>JSON.parse(resultlist);
```

Or:

```
// Assume you have received the json in object form in 'resultlist' variable
let dataList = <Array<UserDetails>>resultlist;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is, create an Object corresponding with the JSON's structure and you assign just the data JSON to the Array of the object.

```js
class User{
   id:string;
   username:string;
   firstName:string;
   lastName:string;
   email:string;
   isActive:boolean;
   isSuperviser:boolean;
}
class JSONData{
   user:User;
   role:string
}
 data:JSONData[] = yourJson.data;
```

You adjust the property name in the json data as in your class and you can handle the data correctly and easily, please refer on this link for [more infos](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html)

Answer (score 0):

`this.userData["role"] = this.user.role` should be  `this.userData["role"] = this.role`

Answer (score 0):

No need to convert. It s already json format but you should use array index then set user variable.

For example :

```
let user:any = {};
user = this.user[arrayIndex].user;

this.userData["user"] = user
this.userData["role"] = this.user[arrayIndex].role;
```

if you want o get data from json array , you should use array index. 
Like this.

```
let user:any = {};
user = this.user[0].user;
this.userData["role"] = this.user[0].role;
```